# AWS CDK: Find out what exact type a parsed apigateway integration is (mock, http, lambda, awsservice)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am reading existing cloudformation and want to read method integrations. The return type of CfnMethod.getIntegration() is "class software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject".  I understand there are 3 different types of Integrations, all extending Integration class. I tried to first cast it to Integration, thinking I would be later able to check if the type of it really is http,aws or lambda integration. But the first step failed:
class software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject cannot be cast to class software.amazon.awscdk.services.apigateway.Integration
Where is my thinking flawed? How do I get the info about what kind of an integration it is? To make it weirder this is in the apigateway integration in the docs:

```
    software.amazon.awscdk.services.apigateway
        Class HttpIntegration
            java.lang.Object
                 software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject
                     software.amazon.awscdk.services.apigateway.Integration
                         software.amazon.awscdk.services.apigateway.HttpIntegration
```

I expected to be able to cast the JsiiObject into an Integration. Result: unable to cast (fails at "Integration" line).

```
public static void execute(HolderForAWSState holderForAWSState){
        List<CfnMethod> work = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IConstruct worker : holderForAWSState.getOrderedConstructs().get(CfnMethod.class)) {
            work.add((CfnMethod) worker);
        }
        for(CfnMethod worker: work){
        System.out.println("Integration class: ");
        System.out.println(worker.getIntegration().getClass());
        Integration integration = (Integration) worker.getIntegration();
        System.out.println(integration.getClass());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of the getClass() println?

Comment: It was in the body of the question: class software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject

Answer (score 0):

CDK is not implemented in Java and doesn't follow any class hierarchies for that matter. CDK is implemented in Typescript and a Java Wrapper provides the interface for it. The core is still running typescript even when running from Java.

A JsiiObject is a proxy for the corresponding Typescript object and as far as I can see CDK doesn't provide support for investigating the type hierarchy comfortably from Java.

I assume that the Integration is created by the CDK itself and not by user code.

Unfortunately I don't see a valid, non-hacky way to achieve this and you might need a completely different solution.

For example use the AWS API to inspect the deployed CDK stack or extract the necessary information from the proxy yourself.

Comment: As you can see below, there is kind of hacky way to deal with it. What annoys me is that neither the restrictions nor the hacky ways are documented anywhere.

Comment: The restriction is documented. Hacky ways ... well they are almost never documented. And my answer still stands: No official supported way, just workarounds and hacks.

Comment: Which restriction is documented? Why would you say that it does not follow class hierarchies? Why are they documented (provided inline) as if they were then?The Integration (which is an Integration Property in the end) was parsed from JSON. It is a static object. I opened a bug on CDK github, let us see how far this goes.

Answer (score 0):

One colleague of mine decided 2 hours with me on this problem is worth it.

We played using an existing CfnMethod worker:

`JsiiObject jsiiObject = (JsiiObject) worker.getIntegration(); System.out.println(jsiiObject.$jsii$toJson());`

outcome:

`{"$jsii.byref":"Object@10049","$jsii.interfaces":["aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.CfnMethod.IntegrationProperty"]}`

How come? So why isn't this method called "getIntegrationProperty()"? Maybe if I cast to it?
`IntegrationProperty intProp = (IntegrationProperty) worker.getIntegration();`

outcome:

`class software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject cannot be cast to class software.amazon.awscdk.services.apigateway.CfnMethod$IntegrationProperty`

????????

After 1 more hour of fumbling around we found out, that the cast is not a direct one, but for whatever reason considered "unsafe" and requires a special static method from a special class, that of course is nowhere documented:
`IntegrationProperty integrationProp = UnsafeCast.unsafeCast(jsiiObject, IntegrationProperty.class);`

Worked like a charm. All Integration Property methods are accessible. Example:

`System.out.println(integrationProp.getClass());`
`System.out.println(integrationProp.getType());`

outcome:

`class software.amazon.awscdk.services.apigateway.CfnMethod$IntegrationProperty$Jsii$Proxy AWS_PROXY`

Thanks Simun!